# Adding a video fails without any error message

Tags: bug, developer-story

For the [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/4632019) (it is me) I can not add video.

1. I click "Blogs or Videos"
2. Put link: https://geekbrains.ru/events/218
3. Technology: git
4. click "Save" and nothing is happen

In response to POST query I got the form back again

Comment: Looks like the image is causing trouble. If you remove the image by clicking the X button, saving works. Some visual feedback with an error message would be nice.

Comment: There is no any error. It is same as I do not click "Save" button at all

Comment: I know, that last sentence is aimed at the devs, not at you :)

Comment: @Stijn I have tried without the image as you advice and it works fine. Thank you.